# Data Changes When Posting in Discord. I Use Discord.py

Tags: python-requests, discord, discord.py

I have this piece of code

````
    @commands.command(name='cheatsh')
    async def cheat_sh_data(self, ctx, language:str, *, query):
        query = query.replace(" ", "%20")
        url = f"https://cheat.sh/{language}/{query}"
        response = requests.request("GET", url=url)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"```{language}\n{response.text[:1900]}```")
````

It prints the data fine when not using it as a discord command but as a normal python function, e.g

```
url = https://cheat.sh/python/lists
it prints
#  python - Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?
#  
#  The general answer is that += tries to call the __iadd__ special
#  method, and if that isn't available it tries to use __add__ instead.
#  So the issue is with the difference between these special methods.
#  
#  The __iadd__ special method is for an in-place addition, that is it
#  mutates the object that it acts on. The __add__ special method returns
#  a new object and is also used for the standard + operator.
#  
#  So when the += operator is used on an object which has an __iadd__
#  defined the object is modified in place. Otherwise it will instead try
#  to use the plain __add__ and return a new object.
#  
#  That is why for mutable types like lists += changes the object's
#  value, whereas for immutable types like tuples, strings and integers a
#  new object is returned instead (a += b becomes equivalent to a = a +
#  b).
#  
#  For types that support both __iadd__ and __add__ you therefore have to
#  be careful which one you use. a += b will call __iadd__ and mutate a,
#  whereas a = a + b will create a new object and assign it to a. They
#  are not the same operation!

>>> a1 = a2 = [1,
None
```

but when im trying the command in discord, the data comes out as this. I want it to print the original text which i get when doing response.text:

```
[38;5;246;03m#  python - Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  The general answer is that += tries to call the __iadd__ special[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  method, and if that isn't available it tries to use __add__ instead.[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  So the issue is with the difference between these special methods.[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  The __iadd__ special method is for an in-place addition, that is it[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  mutates the object that it acts on. The __add__ special method returns[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  a new object and is also used for the standard + operator.[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  So when the += operator is used on an object which has an __iadd__[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  defined the object is modified in place. Otherwise it will instead try[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  to use the plain __add__ and return a new object.[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  That is why for mutable types like lists += changes the object's[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  value, whereas for immutable types like tuples, strings and integers a[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  new object is returned instead (a += b becomes equivalent to a = a +[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  b).[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  For types that support both __iadd__ and __add__ you therefore have to[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  be careful which one you use. a += b will call __iadd__ and mutate a,[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  whereas a = a + b will create a new object and assign it to a. They[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  are not the same operation![39;00m

[38;5;252m>>[39m[38;5;252m>[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252ma1[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252m=[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252ma2[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252m=[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252m[[39m[38;5;67m1[39m[38;5;252m,
```

I don't know how to use beautiful soup so any solution regarding requests library is appreciated. And also the data discord prints what kind of data is this??
Any Help Will Be Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some regex would do the trick:

```
import re
text = """
[38;5;246;03m#  python - Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  The general answer is that += tries to call the __iadd__ special[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  method, and if that isn't available it tries to use __add__ instead.[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  So the issue is with the difference between these special methods.[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  The __iadd__ special method is for an in-place addition, that is it[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  mutates the object that it acts on. The __add__ special method returns[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  a new object and is also used for the standard + operator.[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  So when the += operator is used on an object which has an __iadd__[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  defined the object is modified in place. Otherwise it will instead try[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  to use the plain __add__ and return a new object.[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  That is why for mutable types like lists += changes the object's[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  value, whereas for immutable types like tuples, strings and integers a[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  new object is returned instead (a += b becomes equivalent to a = a +[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  b).[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  [39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  For types that support both __iadd__ and __add__ you therefore have to[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  be careful which one you use. a += b will call __iadd__ and mutate a,[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  whereas a = a + b will create a new object and assign it to a. They[39;00m
[38;5;246;03m#  are not the same operation![39;00m

[38;5;252m>>[39m[38;5;252m>[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252ma1[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252m=[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252ma2[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252m=[39m[38;5;252m [39m[38;5;252m[[39m[38;5;67m1[39m[38;5;252m,
"""
output = re.sub(r"\>\>.*", "", re.sub(r"\[\d{2}(;\d*)+m", "", text))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
#  python - Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?
#
#  The general answer is that += tries to call the __iadd__ special
#  method, and if that isn't available it tries to use __add__ instead.
#  So the issue is with the difference between these special methods.
#
#  The __iadd__ special method is for an in-place addition, that is it
#  mutates the object that it acts on. The __add__ special method returns
#  a new object and is also used for the standard + operator.
#
#  So when the += operator is used on an object which has an __iadd__
#  defined the object is modified in place. Otherwise it will instead try
#  to use the plain __add__ and return a new object.
#
#  That is why for mutable types like lists += changes the object's
#  value, whereas for immutable types like tuples, strings and integers a
#  new object is returned instead (a += b becomes equivalent to a = a +
#  b).
#
#  For types that support both __iadd__ and __add__ you therefore have to
#  be careful which one you use. a += b will call __iadd__ and mutate a,
#  whereas a = a + b will create a new object and assign it to a. They
#  are not the same operation!
```